# C++ Regarding cin.ignore()

Tags: c++

i would hope someone can modify my code as its so buggy. sometime its work, sometime it dont..

so let me explain more.. Text file data is as below

```
Line3D, [70, -120, -3], [-29, 1, 268]
Line3D, [25, -69, -33], [-2, -41, 58]
```

To read the above line.. i use the following

```
char buffer[30];

cout << "Please enter filename: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,filename);

readFile.open(filename.c_str());

//if successfully open
if(readFile.is_open())
{
//record counter set to 0
numberOfRecords = 0;

while(readFile.good())
{
//input stream get line by line
readFile.getline(buffer,20,',');


if(strstr(buffer,"Point3D"))
{
Point3D point3d_tmp;
readFile>>point3d_tmp;

// and so on...
```

Then i did a overload on the ifstream for Line3d

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream &input,Line3D &line3d)
{
int x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2;

//get x1
input.ignore(2);
input>>x1;

//get y1
input.ignore();
input>>y1;

//get z1
input.ignore();
input>>z1;

//get x2
input.ignore(4);
input>>x2;

//get y2
input.ignore();
input>>y2;

//get z2
input.ignore();
input>>z2;
input.ignore(2);

Point3D pt1(x1,y1,z1);
Point3D pt2(x2,y2,z2);

line3d.setPt1(pt1);
line3d.setPt2(pt2);

line3d.setLength();
}
```

But the issue is the record work sometime and sometime it dont.. what i mean is if at this point

```
//i add a cout
cout << x1 << y1 << z1;
cout << x2 << y2 << z2;

//its works!
Point3D pt1(x1,y1,z1);
Point3D pt2(x2,y2,z2);

line3d.setPt1(pt1);
line3d.setPt2(pt2);

line3d.setLength();
```

but if i take away the cout it dont work. how do i change my cin.ignore() so the data can be handle properly , consider number range is -999 to 999

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why this code is crashing. It's probably because you have bugs you haven't posted here. However you will find it easier to write operator>> this way.

```
istream& operator>>(istream &input,Line3D &line3d)
{
    int x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2;
    char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7;

    input >> c1 >> x1 >> c2 >> y1 >> c3 >> z1 >> c4 >> c5 >> x2 >> c6 >> y2 >> c7 >> z2;

    Point3D pt1(x1,y1,z1);
    Point3D pt2(x2,y2,z2);

    line3d.setPt1(pt1);
    line3d.setPt2(pt2);
    line3d.setLength();
    return input;

}
```

Use dummy char variables (c1, c2 etc.) to read in the commas and brackets you aren't interested in. This technique will also skip the spaces you aren't interested in. This is a much more realiable method than using ignore.

Other errors in your code are that `operator>>` should use `istream` not `ifstream`, and it should have `return input;` at the end. By writing your `operator>>` to use `istream` it will then work with any kind of input stream (including `cin` for instance) not just with file streams.